# web URL variable doesn't like spaces in Powershell

Tags: workflow, powershell, url

I'm relatively new to PowerShell and getting my head around a script i am modifying for my environment.

Simply put, I need to add a URL as a variable to my script, but there is a space in it. I have tried replacing the space with a '%20' but it still doesn't resolve.

```
$WebUrl = "http://sharepoint.acceptance/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Workflow History/"
```

and

```
$WebUrl = "http://sharepoint.acceptance/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Workflow%20History/"
```

when validated with

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl -ea SilentlyContinue
if($Web -eq $null)
{
   Write-Error "The web with URL '$WebUrl' was not found, halting execution."
   break
}
else {
write-host "$WebUrl is good"
}
```

both return

```
"The web with URL 'http://sharepoint.acceptance/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Workflow%20History/' was not found, halting execution."
```

in each case.
I'm sure what I am doing is just a matter of bad syntax but I'm just not experienced enough to see the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the space, having a space in a web url variable is fine.

The problem seems to be that your WEB url needs to be the Website link and you're providing a link to the workflow history list.

e.g.

web url --> http://contoso.com/site1

list url --> http://contoso.com/site1/lists/workflow history

TL;DR assign $WebUrl the url for your website, not your list

Comment: Thankyou, yes i was calling one layer too deep.